# can't locate spreadsheet writeexcel.pm

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

i am getting Error

> can't locate spreadsheet writeexcel.pm in @inc @inc contains

yes i know, it require the excel plugin,

am using straberry perl,

tell me where i find the excel plugin for PERL, and where  shoukld paste that excel plugin

Comment: **yOUR cAPitALizaTIoN iS inaCURAte:** Perl is a *case-sensitive* programming language, and thus its identifiers and strings must be treated with greater care than you’ve shown here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the module on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm). To install it on strawberry perl interactively, do

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

or (non-interactive)

```
cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

---

**Edit:**

If you get any errors about unfulfilled dependencies (missing modules like `OLE::Storage_Lite`), install these dependencies using `cpan <dependency>` and then continue installation of your package.

If you don't need to stick on Strawberry Perl, you could switch over to [ActiveState Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) which comes with an integrated package manager (PPM) that installs the required modules (including dependencies). ActiveState provides a repository with pre-built modules, so they don't need to be compiled.

---

Is `@INC` really empty? If so, you have to set `@INC` in order to specify the include directories for perl to search for modules.

Furthermore, I'd expect that the error message would read

> can't locate Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.pm ...

if you specified the dependency correctly with `use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;`.

Comment: how to install , this excel plugin in my system,

Comment: @Bharanikumar: what do you exactly mean? I told you how to install: either using `cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` or by the interactive method...

Comment: i just downloaded the spreadsheet::WriteExcel plugin, i followed the read procedure, fir that am getting error like C:\sample\Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37>perl Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite OLE::Storage_Lite 0.19 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Parse::RecDescent 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Comment: Then i tried C:\sample\OLE-Storage_Lite-0.19>perl Makefile.PL
Writing Makefile for OLE::Storage_Lite , that's why,  am asking basic plugin installtion procedure

Comment: such great advise, installed above plugin very easily with this CPAN command..keep it up man

Comment: @Bharanikumar: Thanks. Don't forget to check the answer. I put my comments in the answer, so I'll delete them here.

Comment: Perl doesn’t have an `@inc` variable; perhaps you meant `@INC`.

Comment: @tchrist: how did you guess that? Right. I'll fix it in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @eckes - he's just THAT GOOD :)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it as root, then you need to execute your script as root as well. This solved the problem for me.